# Changin IRC default client on Mavericks

Tags: macos, defaults

I installed [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) and then [LimeChat](http://limechat.net/) IRC clients. I realized Colloquy opens automatically when clicking on a link like irc://irc.freenode.net/kolab
How can I changed these links to open in LimeChat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set defaults using something like [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (old but free & still functional)

Use the URLS header & set your default app by finding the protocol in the URLs list & selecting the default in the drop menu on the right.

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Glad it helped :)